# How do I keep label text side by side with label value in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to keep the label text value: "This is the subtotal" next to subtotal value. Meaning:

[image]

If I were to click on the "Calulate Subtotal" Button the text "This is the subtotal" should be to the right and the actual subtotal should be to the left. Currently, If I were to click on the "Calulate Subtotal" Button the text "this is the subtotal" disappears. Can someone steer me in the right direction?

```
try:
import Tkinter as tk
except:
  import tkinter as tk

class GetInterfaceValues():
    def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.geometry('500x200')
    self.button = tk.Button(self.root,
                            text='Calculate Subtotal',
                            command=self.getSubtotals)
    self.button.pack()

    self.firstLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text="This is the subtotal:")

    self.firstLabel.pack()

    self.root.mainloop()

def getSubtotals(self):
    self.firstLabel["text"] = 55*10



 app = GetInterfaceValues()
```

Comment: Change `self.firstLabel["text"] = 55*10` to `self.firstLabel["text"] = "This is the subtotal: " + str(55*10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change your `getSubtotals` method to retain the current text of `firstLabel` as the following:

```py
def getSubtotals(self):
    self.firstLabel["text"] = self.firstLabel["text"] + str(55 * 10)
```

Couple of suggestions:

- You might want to create another widget to show subtotal value other than `firstLabel`.
- You might want to restructure your class so that you only initialize the attributes in the init method
- Please check the indentations and code formatting when asking questions to make it easier for others to inspect your code

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the response. Can you elaborate more on your first bullet point?

Comment: Your solution will include previous results if the function is executed many times.

Comment: @acw1668 `self.firstLabel["text"] can be substituted with the string "This is the subtotal: "

Comment: @RooseveltH Maybe leave the text value of `firstLabel` as static string, "This is the subtotal: " and create another widget for dynamic numeric values.